# android - К чему ведут все корни отображения элементов?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Очень интересно, а как работают разметки? `LinearLayout`, к примеру. Ведь когда мы пишем

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Да и вообще любые атрибуты.... В классе `LinearLayout` все это читается и как отрисовывается? Неужели по координатам? `Lyout`-ы, как и любые другие виджеты наследуются от `View`, а что дальше? Где конец? Где класс, для отрисовки? Если по координатам, то что же это за монстры писали андроид? Просто представить не могу, это же жесть.

Comment: Что, если посмотреть исходники класса [`View`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View) (или [`ViewGroup`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup) в случае контейнеров) и его наследников, например того же [`LinearLayout`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#LinearLayout)

Comment: Вообще, устройство виджетов неплохо описано "изнутри" [в документации](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) на примере создания собственного класса-виджета